# About putting computer to sleep in the middle of a feature update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

[image]

I have to put my computer to sleep in this situation. Will there be any harm to the update files? What can I do?

Comment: Never done this but assume the updates will resume without issue after waking from sleep.

Comment: @Moab It's continuing i really hope that there is no damage to the update files.

Comment: Why do you "have to put your machine in a sleep state", why can't you perform the update, then place it in sleep mode?  Understanding the reason, this must be done, can help us formulate an answer that avoids any potential problems from doing so.  Edit your question to include this vital information

Comment: @Ramhound I had to move places. I was outside. Anyways it's over now i put it in sleep then opened it now. It's continuing.

Comment: As @Moab stated, it should (and did) resume,  but if there is ever an issue, you can always download an update from  Microsoft and then (re)install it.

Comment: That depends on what stage you interrupted it. In most of the cases it should be ok to move it to sleep mode, because Windows should pause the operations, but potentially there could be a problem in further configuring a specific update. When FU in 'Installing' stage it's downloading and replacing files in ~WINDOWS.BT folder. The further configuration of the system is done after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

They will not continue to download, but Windows will wake-up at the pre-determined update time to apply updates (usually 3am by default).  This only works if the computer is asleep... if it is fully shut-down or in hibernate mode, it will not turn itself on.

Source: [Do downloads and updates continue while computer is in sleep mode?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/do-downloads-and-updates-continue-while-computer/fce6617d-646e-4c82-ac35-f6c3f9d98b30)

Windows Update supports pausing and restarting downloads. You do not have to worry if you need to shut down your computer, or if you have lost your Internet connection while an update is downloading. Once the connection is reestablished, the download will continue where it left off.

If your computer is not turned on during the scheduled time for installing updates, the Windows Update agent will try to wake up the PC (if the PC was asleep), or wait for the PC to be turned on again. As soon as the PC is running again, it will install the updates.